# netbeans manifest.mf is read-only because it is inside

Tags: netbeans, jar, manifest, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I want to change contains of file Meta-inf/Manifest.mf . I try this:

```
 org.openide.filesystems.FileObject projectDirectory = project.getProjectDirectory();

 FileObject modulesFileObject = projectDirectory.getFileObject("build/cluster/modules/");

 properties.store(propertiesFile.getOutputStream(), null);
```

but I got this Exeption:

```
manifest.mf is read-only because it is inside.
```

Jar file is not read-only. So can you help me, please?

PS: I use NetBeans Platform RCP 7.11 , java 1.7_07

Thank Jirka

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the JarSystem is read-only.

Jirka